# Choosing Google Cloud Storage object name when uploading a file using Python blobstore API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am migrating from the blobstore to Google Cloud Storage in my Google App Engine python app. I would like to use the blobstore API when uploading to GCS.
That is perfectly OK, according to [GAE python documentation regarding blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage)

The flow works just like for storing to blobstore. The client requests upload URL, blobstore.create_upload_url(...) creates it, client uploads the file via multipart POST, and then server redirects to the upload handler in my GAE application.

The problem with this is that though I got to choose the GCS bucket (it is one of the parameters of the  create_upload_url call) I don't see how I can choose the file name. I would like to break it down into folders.
The inspiration comes from the

[Google App Engine Blobstore to Google Cloud Storage Migration Tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-blobstoremigrator-python/blob/master/src/app/migrator.py)
where the filename is broken so that browsing of the GCS "folders" is manageable.

I know of just one way of naming the GCS file - to forego blobstore API.
Instead the client would upload the file to the GAE handler, which would use lib.cloudstorage to write the file data into the GCS - exacly like the quoted Migration tool does.

I would lose GCS goodies like retries on errors during upload.

The question: is there a way to upload file directly to GCS, while impacting the way the resulting GCS object is named.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods?hl=bg#postobject

Comment: or use gcs copy, delete to rename the object after the blobstore gcs upload

Comment: or or use blobstore upload and move (write) it to gcs

Answer (score 0):

Repository : https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload

Example code for the first option.

- where you can name the bucket object
- and use a signed url to access the bucket

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods?hl=bg#postobject

The upload template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>'gcs_upload'</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://storage.googleapis.com/{{ form_bucket }}"
          method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="key" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="{{ form_access_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-read">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{{ form_succes_redirect }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{ form_policy }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{ form_signature }}">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The upload form handler:

```
class GcsUpload(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):

        default_bucket = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
        google_access_id = app_identity.get_service_account_name()
        succes_redirect = 'http://www.example.com/success'
        policy_string = """
        {"expiration": "2015-06-22T18:11:11Z",
                  "conditions": [
                      ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
                      {"acl": "bucket-owner-read"},
                      {"success_action_redirect": "%s"},
                  ]}""" % succes_redirect

        policy = base64.b64encode(policy_string)
        _, signature_bytes = app_identity.sign_blob(policy)
        signature = base64.b64encode(signature_bytes)

        self.render_template('gcs_upload.html', form_bucket=default_bucket, form_succes_redirect=succes_redirect,
                             form_access_id=google_access_id, form_signature=signature, form_policy=policy)
```